# contents of config directory created by scaffold tool

Tags: yesod

Would someone please explain why directory "config" of the application created by the scaffold tool has favicon.ico file in it. it seems to me that .ico files belong to the "static" directory. why is it there?

thanks

konstantin

Answer (score 0):

We use SO for help questions. please bring these types of question to the yesod mail list.